# NVidia SolidWireFrame

Tags: directx

I'm wanting to display some geometries using the solidwireframe, it appears to be a fx file with multiple effects and single passes.

So i wrote a class to perform what i thought the effect file was doing. The Header files are my Compiled Shaders, which are copies of the NVidia ones. compiled with version 4.0

```
# include "SolidWireFrame.h"
# include "WireGeometryShader.h"
# include "GeometryShader.h"
# include "WirePixelShader.h"
# include "ColorPixelShader.h"
# include "WireVertexShader.h"

namespace DirectX11DrawingAdapter
{
    SolidWireFrame::SolidWireFrame()
    {
    }

    bool SolidWireFrame::Init(ID3D11Device* device)
    {
        m_pdepthLessEqualStencilState = nullptr;
        m_pfillRasterizerState = nullptr;
        m_pBlendingState = nullptr;
        m_pdepthWriteLessStencilState = nullptr;
        m_vertexShader = nullptr;
        m_geometryShader = nullptr;
        m_pixelColorShader = nullptr;
        m_geometrySolidWireShader = nullptr;
        m_pixelSolidWireShader = nullptr;
        m_vertexLayout = nullptr;
        if (!InitializeDepthStencilState(device))
            return false;
        if (!InitializeRaterizerState(device))
            return false;
        if (!InitializeBlendState(device))
            return false;
        if (!InitializeVertexShader(device))
            return false;
        if (!InitializeGeometryShader(device))
            return false;
        if (!InitializePixelShader(device))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    void SolidWireFrame::ApplySolidWirePattern(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext)
    {       
        SetDepthStencilState(deviceContext, m_pdepthLessEqualStencilState);
        SetRasterizerState(deviceContext, m_pfillRasterizerState);
        SetBlendState(deviceContext, m_pBlendingState);
        deviceContext->VSSetShader(m_vertexShader, NULL, 0);
        deviceContext->GSSetShader(m_geometrySolidWireShader, NULL, 0);
        deviceContext->PSSetShader(m_pixelSolidWireShader, NULL, 0);
    }

    void SolidWireFrame::ApplyDepthAndSolid(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext)
    {
        SetDepthStencilState(deviceContext, m_pdepthWriteLessStencilState);
        SetRasterizerState(deviceContext, m_pfillRasterizerState);
        SetBlendState(deviceContext, m_pBlendingState);
        deviceContext->VSSetShader(m_vertexShader, NULL, 0);
        deviceContext->GSSetShader(m_geometryShader, NULL, 0);
        deviceContext->PSSetShader(m_pixelColorShader, NULL, 0);
    }

    void SolidWireFrame::ApplyDepthOnly(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext)
    {
        SetDepthStencilState(deviceContext, m_pdepthWriteLessStencilState);
        SetRasterizerState(deviceContext, m_pfillRasterizerState);
        SetBlendState(deviceContext, m_pnoColorBlendingState);
        deviceContext->VSSetShader(m_vertexShader, NULL, 0);
        deviceContext->GSSetShader(m_geometryShader, NULL, 0);
        deviceContext->PSSetShader(m_pixelColorShader, NULL, 0);
    }

    void SolidWireFrame::ApplySolidOnly(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext)
    {
        SetDepthStencilState(deviceContext, m_pdepthLessEqualStencilState);
        SetRasterizerState(deviceContext, m_pfillRasterizerState);
        SetBlendState(deviceContext, m_pBlendingState);
        deviceContext->VSSetShader(m_vertexShader, NULL, 0);
        deviceContext->GSSetShader(m_geometryShader, NULL, 0);
        deviceContext->PSSetShader(m_pixelColorShader, NULL, 0);
    }

    bool SolidWireFrame::InitializeBlendState(ID3D11Device* device)
    {
        D3D11_BLEND_DESC blendStateDescription;
        // Clear the blend state description.
        ZeroMemory(&blendStateDescription, sizeof(D3D11_BLEND_DESC));
        blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].BlendEnable = TRUE;
        blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
        blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
        blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
        blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
        blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_DEST_ALPHA;
        blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].BlendOpAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
        blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;

        // Create the blend state using the description.
        HRESULT result = device->CreateBlendState(&blendStateDescription, &m_pBlendingState);
        if (FAILED(result))
        {
            return false;
        }

        //ZeroMemory(&blendStateDescription, sizeof(D3D11_BLEND_DESC));
        blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].BlendEnable = FALSE;
        result = device->CreateBlendState(&blendStateDescription, &m_pnoColorBlendingState);
        if (FAILED(result))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    bool SolidWireFrame::InitializeDepthStencilState(ID3D11Device* device)
    {
        D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC depthStencilDesc;
        // Initialize the description of the stencil state.
        ZeroMemory(&depthStencilDesc, sizeof(depthStencilDesc));
        // Set up the description of the stencil state.
        depthStencilDesc.DepthEnable = TRUE;
        depthStencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ZERO;
        depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS_EQUAL;

        depthStencilDesc.StencilEnable = FALSE;
        depthStencilDesc.StencilReadMask = 255;
        depthStencilDesc.StencilWriteMask = 255;
        depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
        depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
        depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
        depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
        depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
        depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
        depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
        depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

        // Create the depth stencil state.
        HRESULT result = device->CreateDepthStencilState(&depthStencilDesc, &m_pdepthLessEqualStencilState);
        if (FAILED(result))
        {
            return false;
        }

        //ZeroMemory(&depthStencilDesc, sizeof(depthStencilDesc));
        depthStencilDesc.DepthEnable = true;
        depthStencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
        depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;

        result = device->CreateDepthStencilState(&depthStencilDesc, &m_pdepthWriteLessStencilState);
        if (FAILED(result))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    bool SolidWireFrame::InitializeRaterizerState(ID3D11Device* device)
    {
        D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC rasterizerDescription;
        ZeroMemory(&rasterizerDescription, sizeof(D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC));
        rasterizerDescription.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
        rasterizerDescription.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_NONE;
        rasterizerDescription.DepthBias = FALSE;
        rasterizerDescription.MultisampleEnable = TRUE;

        rasterizerDescription.FrontCounterClockwise = FALSE;
        rasterizerDescription.DepthBiasClamp = 0.000000000;
        rasterizerDescription.SlopeScaledDepthBias = 0.000000000;
        rasterizerDescription.DepthClipEnable = TRUE;
        rasterizerDescription.ScissorEnable = FALSE;
        rasterizerDescription.AntialiasedLineEnable = FALSE;

        HRESULT hr = device->CreateRasterizerState(&rasterizerDescription, &m_pfillRasterizerState);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    bool SolidWireFrame::SetDepthStencilState(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, ID3D11DepthStencilState* depthStencilState)
    {
        deviceContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(depthStencilState, 0);
        return false;
    }

    bool SolidWireFrame::SetRasterizerState(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, ID3D11RasterizerState* raterizerState)
    {
        deviceContext->RSSetState(raterizerState);
        return false;
    }

    bool SolidWireFrame::SetBlendState(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, ID3D11BlendState* blendState)
    {
        float blendFactor[4];
        // Setup the blend factor.
        blendFactor[0] = 0.0f;
        blendFactor[1] = 0.0f;
        blendFactor[2] = 0.0f;
        blendFactor[3] = 0.0f;
        // Turn off the alpha blending.
        deviceContext->OMSetBlendState(blendState, blendFactor, 0xffffffff);
        return false;
    }

    bool SolidWireFrame::InitializeVertexShader(ID3D11Device* device)
    {
        // Create the vertex shader
        HRESULT hr = device->CreateVertexShader(m_pwireVertexShader, sizeof(m_pwireVertexShader), NULL, &m_vertexShader);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Define the input layout
        D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
        {
            { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
            { "NORMAL", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
            { "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 24, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        };

        UINT numElements = ARRAYSIZE(layout);

        // Create the input layout
        hr = device->CreateInputLayout(layout, numElements, m_pwireVertexShader, sizeof(m_pwireVertexShader), &m_vertexLayout);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    bool SolidWireFrame::InitializeGeometryShader(ID3D11Device* device)
    {
        // Create the geometry shader
        HRESULT hr = device->CreateGeometryShader(m_pwireGeometryShader, sizeof(m_pwireGeometryShader), NULL, &m_geometrySolidWireShader);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            return false;

        hr = device->CreateGeometryShader(m_pgeometryShader, sizeof(m_pgeometryShader), NULL, &m_geometryShader);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    bool SolidWireFrame::InitializePixelShader(ID3D11Device* device)
    {
        // Create the pixel shader
        HRESULT hr = device->CreatePixelShader(m_pwirePixelShader, sizeof(m_pwirePixelShader), NULL, &m_pixelSolidWireShader);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            return false;

        hr = device->CreatePixelShader(m_pcolorPixelShader, sizeof(m_pcolorPixelShader), NULL, &m_pixelColorShader);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

now in my application, at the end of Initializing the Device and Context etc. i call.

```
        SolidWireFrame* solidWireFrame = new SolidWireFrame();
        solidWireFrame->Init(m_pd3dDevice.Get());
        m_solidWireFrame.reset(solidWireFrame);
```

and my render loop.

```
    //m_solidWireFrame->ApplyDepthAndSolid(m_pImmediateContext);
    //m_solidWireFrame->ApplyDepthOnly(m_pImmediateContext);
    //m_solidWireFrame->ApplySolidOnly(m_pImmediateContext);

    /*for (it_drawingData iterator = dd.begin(); iterator != dd.end(); iterator++)
    {
        DrawingData *drawingData = iterator->second;
        if (drawingData->IsRendered)
        {
            m_pImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &drawingData->VertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);
            m_pImmediateContext->IASetIndexBuffer(drawingData->IndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0);
            m_pImmediateContext->DrawIndexed(drawingData->IndexData.size(), 0, 0);
        }
    }
    //not sure if i should call this between renders?
    m_pdesignerSwapChain->Present(0, 0);*/

    m_solidWireFrame->ApplySolidWirePattern(m_pImmediateContext);

    for (it_drawingData iterator = dd.begin(); iterator != dd.end(); iterator++)
    {
        DrawingData *drawingData = iterator->second;
        if (drawingData->IsRendered)
        {
            m_pImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &drawingData->VertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);
            m_pImmediateContext->IASetIndexBuffer(drawingData->IndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0);
            m_pImmediateContext->DrawIndexed(drawingData->IndexData.size(), 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sure they can be converted. What is the problem/question?

Comment: I figured the effect was just a wrapper.

Comment: I added my code for the class i created. So i thought i could just create methods to change the state. so during my render loop i call Apply to set the new states then push my buffers out to be drawn. however i see nothing on screen. Note: this works with my regular vs and ps. So i guess my question is. are those SetDepthStencilState, SetRasterizerState and SetBlendState setting parts of their ID3D11_**_DESC to different settings than i am.

Comment: oic now. i got the nvidia sample to compile and i debugged it. seems they render each mesh twice. once with effect 0 and second with effect 8. I have only defined effect 8 and do one render.

Comment: Well, now i am stuck. I converted each Effect, there were 8 into separate calls. eg) effect (8) would SetDepthStencilState, SetRasterizerState, SetBlendState, SetShader, SetGeometryShader and SetPixelShader. InputLayout is same for all. Then i call my Render Routine. SetVertexBuffer, SetIndexbuffer, DrawIndexed. The Demo from Nvidia displays a wireframe after unchecking all but the Draw Wireframe Technique which is effect 8. Mine Displays nothing. i call ID3D10DepthStencilState->GetDesc, ID3D10RasterizerState->GetDesc and ID3D10BlendState->GetDesc to check states. Could my shape be inside out?

Comment: Would appear the algorithm is expecting the first edge for each triangle to be the diagonal.

Comment: I guess nobody can help me out with this. I will attempt to implement the nvidia wireframe code as an effect and see if it works with my geometries.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

I was not setting the world, view, projection constant buffer for the wireframe vs.